# Activerecord initialize attribute after mass_assign

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, activerecord

I have a model inheriting `ActiveRecord::Base` with the following attributes in database:

#### scheduler.rb

```
#  id               :integer          not null, primary key
#  next_datetime    :datetime
#  first_datetime   :datetime
#  created_at       :datetime         not null
#  updated_at       :datetime         not null
```

The objects in this model should be instantiated like this:

```
scheduler.new(first_datetime: DateTime.new(2016, 1, 1))
```

When the object is created (not necessarily saved to database), I would like to copy the attribute in `first_datetime` to `next_datetime`, so that I never get `nil` when I access `my_scheduler.next_datetime`.

I have tried to use `after_initialize` callback, but by the time this code is executed the mass assigned attributes are not available yet.

How can I get this attribute initialized? Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The only thing I can think of is to override the `initialize` method of `ActiveRecord::Base` in such a way that you can add this little customization after the superclass of your model ends its processing.

That could be accomplished as follows:

```
def initialize(attributes = nil, options = {})
  super
  next_datetime ||= first_datetime
end
```

Hope this can help you!

Answer (score 0):

Have you used after_initialize like this?:

```
 after_initiation :set_next_datetime

 def set_next_datetime
  if new_record?
    next_datetime ||= first_datetime
  end
 end
```

Answer (score 0):

Using [tap](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.2.3/Object.html#method-i-tap) might help:

```
scheduler.new(first_datetime: DateTime.new(2016, 1, 1)).tap do |record|
  record.next_datetime = record.first_datetime
end
```